# Plotting heatmaps of multiple columns using slider in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, slider, heatmap

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 4),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 10),
  col1 = rexp(20),
  col2 = rnorm(20), 
  col3 = rexp(20)
)
```

And this is the plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = col2)) + geom_tile()
```

I want to make an interactive chart where I can use a slider change the target column (switching between column 1, 2 and 3).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `frame` aesthetic in the `ggplotly` function from `plotly` to make an interactive slider with your target (I am not sure what your target feature is) like this:

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 4),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 10),
  col1 = rexp(20),
  col2 = rnorm(20), 
  col3 = rexp(20)
)

df$target <- rep(sample(c(1:3), 2), 10)
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = col2, frame = target)) + geom_tile()
ggplotly(plot)
```

Output:

[image]